# NSScrollView incorrect scrolling

Tags: objective-c, macos, scroll, nsscrollview

I have `NSScrollView` in witch is placed `NSClipView` with `NSOpenGLView` inside. When I try to scroll for example to the left. Its OK. But if I then want to scroll to bottom, bottom scroller jumps to right. The same is happening if: I scroll to the bottom, and then try to scroll to the left. Side scroller jumps to the top. What could be my problem?

P.S. I am using `AGCenteringClipView`

Answer (score 0):

There is something in AGCenteringClipView that force the content to be aligned in some way that is wrong to you. It's no easy to give you an answer without code and deeper descriptions. 
Had you correctly setted up the content view?